# How do you install Ubuntu straight onto your computer

Tags: installation

Is there a way to not have to put ubuntu on to a disc or USB?

Comment: It might help if you could describe in *way* more detail what you want to do. Is the [normal installation procedure](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-desktop) not what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer), the Windows Ubuntu installer.

[image]

It lets you to install Ubuntu alongside windows without a CD or USB.  See the [WubiGuide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) if you want more information.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative (although a bit of a "chicken and egg" problem) is to install through the network. See a complete tutorial for building a PXE install server here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallServer

Of course that assumes you have an Ubuntu server running, which I guess kinda defeats your purpose.

Perhaps if you give some details about why you can't (or don't want to) use either USB or CD to install, someone can suggest a solution that can solve your particular problem.